# Unexpected Window Snapping on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, window

Today, while using Ubuntu 20.04, at some point my windows started unexpectedly snapping when I moved them around.  I have no idea what triggered it.

One minute I can easily drag windows around anywhere on the screen, the next minute, they insist on snapping.  Snapping to screen edges, screen corners, or the edges of other windows.

I've been using this same system for about 2 weeks - this is the first time I ran into this problem.

Any ideas how this can happen?  There are no tiling extensions installed, to the best of my knowledge.  Looking at the current keyboard shortcuts, nothing appears related to snapping.

Any help tracking this down would be greatly appreciated.

BTW, the problem was fixed, this time, by logging out of the gnome-shell session and logging in again.

UPDATE:
With windows moving normally, I found that holding down the SHIFT key causes the exact same operation.  Perhaps I had a "stuck shift" state on the system somehow?  I'm using barrier and this system is the client, so that could be involved